# Исходники WordPress сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

Смотрел исходники моего сайта на wp, вот например:

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?> - <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
```

Почему просто не сделать так?

```
<title><?php wp_title();  bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
```

И почти во всех файлах, php код вставлен в php

например:

```
<?php if(isMessage()) ?>
тут html код
<? endif ?>
```

Где можно про это почитать, чем это хорошо и когда так делать?

Comment: Они, вероятно, придерживаются стиля "HTML со вставками PHP", полагая, что так код более читаем и понятен не-программерам, а знакомым только с html. Ниже порог входа. 

Ваш вариант "просто не сдеать так.." упустил из вида " - " между выводами этих функций. Вот и пример, почему лучше их версия : )

Comment: По-хорошему надо использовать хорошие шаблонизаторы (например, twig) и всякие gridview, потому что шаблоны любой серьезной штуки рано или поздно превращаются в вырвиглазный ад.  
Разработчики WP про такие вещи не знают, поэтому приходится иметь дело с тем, что есть. Вообще скоро уже можно будет свободно использовать конструкции <?= ?>, не боясь за поддержку сервером, и тогда шаблоны станут немного читаемей.  
Насчет хорошо/плохо: конструкции с if будут присутствовать всегда, выносить сложные проверки в функции тоже приходится всегда. Можно просто изменить сам подход, но суть останется той же.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный вами код

```
<title><?php wp_title(); bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
```

отличается от оригинала тем, что в оригинале между вставками присутствует тире/минус.

В случаях с if, for, while и т.д. для улучшения читабельности при инлайновых вставках кода чаще применяется именно такая конструкция. Почитать про это можно в [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Но вообще смешивание php-кода с HTML - дурной тон. Часто эта задача решается шаблонизаторами (но не в случае с Wordpress).